# Prove that :$\frac{1}{a+b} +\frac{1}{b+c} +\frac{1}{c+a}\ge \frac{4}{a^2+7} +\frac{4}{b^2+7} +\frac{4}{c^2+7}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $a,b,c>0$ and satisfying $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$.

Prove that :$\dfrac{1}{a+b} +\dfrac{1}{b+c} +\dfrac{1}{c+a}\ge \dfrac{4}{a^2+7} +\dfrac{4}{b^2+7} +\dfrac{4}{c^2+7}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AM-GM we have :

$\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}\ge\frac{2}{\sqrt{(a+b)(b+c)}}\ge\frac{4}{a+2b+c}\ge\frac{4}{\frac{a^2+1}{2}+b^2+1+\frac{c^2+1}{2}}=\frac{8}{(a^2+b^2+c^2)+4+b^2}=\frac{8}{b^2+7}$

Similar, the inequality is proved.

Comment: You can omit the second expression using $AM \ge HM$